# How do I insert an Oracle DATE object in UTC TZ without changing default TimeZone and without a PreparedStatement?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, timezone

I have a column in my Oracle database called `changed_utc`. I want to insert a row with this column set to a value of the specified time so it arrives in the `DATE` column as UTC.

Caveat:

- I can't change the `TimeZone.defaultTimeZone`

Comment: You lost me. "With this column set to a value of the specified time so it arrives in the DATE column as UTC." What does that mean?

Comment: In general, storing a date-only field in UTC is not a great idea unless it just so happens that your business rules are aligned to the UTC day.  I recommend you either store the UTC date and time (so you can convert back if desired), or just store the business-relevant date without any conversion to UTC.  For example, if you are storing birthdates, anniversary dates, hire dates, etc. - do NOT convert them to UTC.

Comment: @MattJohnson I am storing date and time.

Comment: @GordThompson, Yes I know that Oracle `DATE` does not have a timezone field.  I merely want the time fields to reflect UTC.

Comment: @GordThompson, I will try that thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PreparedStatement.setTimestamp(int parameterIndex, Timestamp x, Calendar cal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-java.util.Calendar-)

If you are using an ORM then you'll have to figure out how to access this setter via that ORM.  If the ORM does not have a way to invoke this then you are stuck.

Answer (score -1):

This will convert the time from the current timezone to UTC. Does this help?

```
select current_timestamp at time zone 'UTC'
```